# moment js add days not working if the year will change

Tags: javascript, momentjs

if we add days and that will result as a next year date, then we receive something else from the expected

```
// Start date (DD/MM/YYYY):
let currentfromdate = '01/10/2021';

// add 6 months:
let maxdate = moment(currentfromdate).add(180, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
let maxdate2 = moment(currentfromdate).add(6, 'months').format('DD/MM/YYYY');

// Actual output in DD/MM/YYYY:
maxdate: "08/07/2021"
maxdate2: "10/07/2021"

// expected output:
maxdate: "29/03/2021"
maxdate2: "31/03/2021"
```

Comment: In the "expected output" it seems you have switched DD and MM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your code is parsing the original date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format by default. You therefore get a parsed date of `Jan 10 2021` from parsing `01/10/2021`, hence when adding 6 months you get a result of `July 10 2021`.

You need to be specifying your parse format like so:

```
const dateParsed = moment(currentfromdate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
```